# Hovers converted to timeout display or tap double tap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, responsive-design

I'm wondering if there is an easy solution in which I could convert hovers to either setTimeout display; where the hovers appear and disappear at a set time; or implement a doubletap solution to display the hover state only on doubletap.

I know you can call functions based on window sizes with JavaScript; using something similar to below.

```
if( $(window).width() > 768 ) {
```

But is there any way in which I could grab all hover states via determining window size (ie. Smart Mobile / Tablet. iOS / Android) and convert those states to appear either on double tap OR for a certain amount of time. And then they disappear.

I'm hoping I could approach this this way; as opposed to rebuilding all my elements for mobile with those solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/download/) to detect touch device. So, the hover state will be only for no-touch device(desktop). Modernizr will add `.touch` or `.no-touch` class to your `html` tag. Then, you can do something like this:

**CSS**

```
.no-touch .class:hover { color: red; }
.touch .hover { color: red; }
```

`.touch` add class `.hover` on touch device only || doubleTap

**SCSS**

```
.class {
    .no-touch & {
        &:hover { color: red; }
    }
}

/* add class .hover on touch device only || doubleTap */  
.hover {
   .touch & { color: red; }
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT** || QuoJS || http://quojs.tapquo.com/

```
$$('.your-class').doubleTap(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');   
});
```

Comment: Modernizr does it all for you...I opt for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic should be somewhat like this.

```
if('ontouchstart' in document) // if it is a touch device
{
    var nStartTime = null;
    $("element").bind('touchstart', function ()
    {
        if(nStartTime && (new Date().getTime() - nStartTime) < 600) // if it is a second tap and it is within 600ms of the first tap, consider it as a double tap
        {
                $(this).trigger('mouseover');
                nStartTime = null;
        }            
        else //consider it as the first tap
        {
            nStartTime = new Date.getTime();
        }
    }
}
```